# Time Picker Error

Tags: asp.net, timepicker

i used the time picker that has described on this link [Time Picker](http://www.asp.net/community/control-gallery/Item.aspx?i=3221)

But i got one parser error while debugging. the error message is: 
Parser Error Message: Unknown server tag 'cc1:TimeSelector'.

How to avoid this one? Please help me..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make sure you register the control at the top of your page:

```
<%@ Register TagPrefix="cc1" TagName="TimeSelector" Assembly="TimePicker" Namespace="MKB.TimePicker"  %>
```