# Registering ASP.Net Time picker control

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, timepicker

I downloaded this time picker control [ASP.NET Time Picker Control](http://www.asp.net/community/control-gallery/Item.aspx?i=3221) however, I am not able to see it in the HTML markup of the page.

Which step am I missing?

**Update:**
Based on the response on this post [Time Picker Error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2131768/time-picker-error), I did enter

```
 `<%@ Register TagPrefix="cc1" TagName="TimeSelector" Assembly="TimePicker" Namespace="MKB.TimePicker"  %>`
```

but I still cannot see it in my HTML marckup

Comment: Your title references control registration. Did you register the control on your page or in your web.config? Please post your code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The instructions you have, are slightly off from my experience.

- Place the dll to a shared folder on your PC.  (Example: C:\ProgramFiles\TimePicker.)
- In Visual Studio ToolBox window, right click in the General area and click Choose Items.
- In the Toolbox Items dialog, click the Browse button towards the bottom.
- Navigate to the dll in C:\ProgramFiles\TimePicker and click Open.
- After you click Open, your Time Picker should be in the list, then click Ok.
- You should be able to see the control in the toolbox.

Answer (score 0):

Add a reference to the TimePicker assembly.

In your webforms .aspx page, add the tag registration to the top:

```
<Register TagPrefix="cc1" TagName="TimeSelector" Assembly="TimePicker" Namespace="MKB.TimePicker"  %>
```

Place the control somewhere on in your HTML, like the following :

```
<cc1:TimeSelector ID="TimeSelector3" runat="server" EnableClock="true" />
```

You should be able to reference the control in your code behind by using:

```
TimeSelector3.{whateverproperty}
```

If you try to reference the control using Javascript, you'll have to pay attention to what the outputted Id is on the client side.  If you are using master pages, it will usually be something like:

```
ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_TimeSelector3
```

but you'll have to verify this by viewing the source as different versions of IIS or .NET can change the naming scheme.

Comment: ok, I did what you suggested. But then how do I reference the control in my html?

Comment: when I try to do a build, I get an error "unknown server tag "cc1:TimeSelector"

Comment: Can you post your source for your HTML page?  There must be something missing that we can't see right now.